# How to add a part of the acquired API to the array defined in component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

For learning, I am trying to create a simple Todo application using Angular 2 + Django Rest Framework.
In order to immediately display the items saved in the input form, I want to implement the function of acquiring the latest one and displaying it.

JSON format WEB API for acquiring the latest one has the following structure.
[image]

function for getting this API is described in todo.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  todo: Todo[] = [];
  newtodo: NewTodo[] = [];
  private Url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo/`
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ){}

  // Acquire one latest todo added
  getNewTodo(): Promise<NewTodo[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.Url+"?limit=1")
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

Components are described in todo.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'todo-list',
  templateUrl: '../templates/todo-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../static/todo-list.component.css']
})
export class TodoListComponent {
  todos: Todo[] = [];
  newtodo: NewTodo[] = [];
  newtodos: Todo[] = [];
  @Input() todo: Todo = new Todo();

  save(): void {
    this.todoService
      .create(this.todo);
  }
}
```

The point I want to teach is the following points.
1.Execute service's getNewTodo () when save () of the component is executed and store the obtained return value in the array `newtodo`.
2.Since only the results part is necessary for the acquired JSON, pull out the results part, push it to the array `newtodos` and pass it to html.

For 1, I think that you should write the following description in save ()

```
this.todoService
  .getNewTodo()
  .then(newtodo => this.newtodo = newtodo);
```

I can not understand what to write about 2.
I'd like to tell you how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can step into the JSON and obtain the content of `results` with the following:

```
getNewTodo(): Promise<NewTodo[]> {
  return this.http
    .get(this.Url+"?limit=1")
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json().results) // here
    .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

You are not showing use the `create`-method in the service, but whatever it looks like, return a promise, so that we in the component can inside the callback call `getNewTodo`:

```
save() {
  this.todoService
    .create(this.todo)
    .then(data => {
       this.getNewTodo(); // here
    })
}
```

and the `getNewTodo` that calls the method in the service:

```
getNewTodo() {
  this.todoService
    .getNewTodo()
    .then(newtodo => {
      this.newtodo = newtodo
    });
}
```